# Is there a way to control the volume of the Skype App in Windows 8.1?

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, skype

So I'm using the Skype app in Windows 8.1 and my wife stepped away from her computer. Her TV is on and whatever show is on turned to a loud car chase. I could just mute my whole computer, but I'd like to be able to hear what's playing on my computer in the meantime.

In Skype for Desktop there are Audio Settings that, while inconveniently placed, allow me to control the volume of Skype.

[image: Audio Settings in Skype for Desktop]

In the Skype app, if I swipe to show the available options, the only options I'm given are for notifications, setting her as a favorite contact, viewing her profile, blocking her, and removing her from my contacts.

[image: Right-clicking the Windows 8.1 Skype Application]

If I go to the settings for the application, I'm given the option to select the default devices for audio and video, but there's nothing about volume.

[image: Settings available in the Windows 8.1 Skype Application]

I've been looking through the Skype forums, and it seems like there are no ways to control the volume of the call in the Skype App itself. So if that's true, is there some way I can control the volume of the Skype App outside of it's built-in settings?

Answer (score 1):

It's a Windows control.

*left* click the speaker icon in the system tray by clock in the taskbar (if it's a hidden icon use the little triangle to get to it).

Click on "Mixer" (a single word just below the single volume control that pops up) then you should see seperate volume controls for each application including one for skype.

(or you can *right* click the speaker and select "Open Volume Mixer" on the popup menu)

If you have multiple audio devices use the "device" selector to change to the appropriate mixer. (that is the mixer for your speakers or headphone or bluetooth or whatever other Audio output device you have).

Edits: because I followed my own directions and found flaws =]

Comment: I checked it and it seems to only work for the desktop version, the app gets bundled into the speakers it looks like.

Comment: I don't use the metro apps (always the desktop PERIOD.), but let me go try.

Comment: Inconclusive, my Skype metro app is apparently out of date and I see no apparent way to tell it to update.