# Is there a way to control the volume of Skype App in Windows 10?

Tags: audio, skype

I followed this post titled, "Is there a way to control the volume of the Skype App in Windows 8.1?" here: [Is there a way to control the volume of the Skype App in Windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/788605/is-there-a-way-to-control-the-volume-of-the-skype-app-in-windows-8-1)

It seems that what is suggested there does not work The problem is new though, since Skype Last update (And Windows 10) more or less. The Windows volume control (Lower right hand corner on the taskbar) seems to do nothing, and in my case the volume heard is often too loud.
Can anyone help?

Comment: no replies?? :-(